# Firestore: Why is my write operation being prevented?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my app, the user creates a group and then adds himself as the first member, but Android Studio is saying that the write failed due to a permissions denied error. Below is the rule and the code that creates the group/adds as member.

**The rule:**

```
match /groups/{groupID}/members/{memberUID} {
  allow read: if generalRules() == true 
                && isMemberOfGroup(groupID, request.auth.uid) == true; // Members can read the subcollection
  allow create, delete: if request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupID)).data.adminUID;
  allow update: if false; // No updates allowed for subcollection documents
}
```

**The code:**

```
Future<String> createGroupFS({required String groupName, required String groupSlogan}) async {
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals
    final timestamp = getFirestoreTimestamp();
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final mainGroupsCollectionPath = globals.mainGroupsCollection();

    final newGroupDoc = firestore.collection(mainGroupsCollectionPath).doc();

    var groupID = newGroupDoc.id;
    final adminUID = globals.currentUID;
    final adminUsername = globals.currentUsername;

    final data = ModelMainGroup(
        groupID: groupID,
        groupName: groupName,
        adminUID: adminUID,
        adminUsername: adminUsername,
        createDate: timestamp,
        creatorUID: adminUID,
        creatorUsername: adminUsername,
        initialGroupCreate: true,
        fireTriggers: true,
    ).toJson();

    newGroupDoc.set(data).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      groupID = '';
      print(globals.debugappNameTag + 'database createGroupFS error: ' + error.toString());
      return groupID;
    });

    //Add current user as the first member
    final mainGroupMembersCollectionRef = globals.mainGroupMembersCollection(groupID: groupID);
    final mainGroupMembersDocRef = firestore.collection(mainGroupMembersCollectionRef).doc(globals.currentUID);

    final membersData = ModelGroupMember(
        username: adminUsername,
        dateAdded: timestamp
    ).toJson();

    mainGroupMembersDocRef.set(membersData);

    return groupID;
  }
```

Comment: Please make sure that the code is self-contains and minimal. For example: `final mainGroupsCollectionPath = globals.mainGroupsCollection()`, we have no way to know what value this is unless you show us. But better yet is to not use a constant in a minimal repro, and reproduce the problem with a hard-coded string. Similarly, do you need the entire `ModelMainGroup` - or can you also reproduce the error with a just the one or two fields that your rules check for?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the first write hasn't completed yet by the time the second one executes, and your rules seem to depends on the results of the first write.

If this is indeed the case, using `await` on the first write should solve that problem.